# Is it possible to vectorize this Python code containing 1D and 2D numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

`actualrgn` is a 1D `numpy.ndarray` of 3145728 elements. `actualrgnexpand` is a 2D `numpy.ndarray` of dimensions 12 x 3145728.

```
for j in range(len(actualrgn)):
    for i in reversed(range(12)):
        if actualrgn[j] >= 2**i:
            actualrgnexpand[i][j] = 1
            actualrgn[j] -= 2**i
```

Is it possible to vectorize the above so that I lose the outer loop over the elements of `actualrgn`? I tried using `numpy.vectorize` but it seemed to struggle to convert a function of a scalar and a vector (to use the mathematical equivalents) to a function of a vector and a matrix. I have also tried finding 'built-in' `ufunc`'s to simplify the above without success.

Comment: If you are using Python 2.x I would suggest to call `xrange` instead of `range` for big arrays. You are saving lot's of space and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way of vectorizing an 'if' statement, is to use a boolean indexing mask.

```
for i in reversed(range(12)):
    I = actualrgn >= 2**i
    actualrgnexpand[i,I] = 1
    actualrgn[I] -= 2**i
```

`actualrgn[I]` are the subset of numbers that should be modified.  The right hand side of these assignments has to be the right size.  A scalar in this case fits all.

Comment: I think you miss-typed `range(range(12))` instead of just `range(12)`.

Comment: yes - incomplete editing, starting with a version that deduced the range from the array size.

Comment: @hpaulj How do I extend the Boolean expression so that I am checking against 2 conditions? I.e. something like `I = actualrgn >= a1 && actualrgn < a2`, but not that, cos I already tried and it didn't work...

Comment: Try `I = (actualrgn>=a1)&(acutalrgn<a2)`.  The goal is to use the element wise `.__and__()` operation on two boolean arrays.  `I` should end up as a boolean array with the same shape as `actualrgn`.  `np.logical_and` also does this.